# JavaScript - Scrolling JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have JavaScript like that:

```
items.forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
                console.log(item.price);
                var message = 'BitSkins Price: $' + item.bprice + '';
                if (item.price != null) {
                    if (item.bprice == '') {
                        message = 'Item never sold on BitSkins!';
                    }
                    if (item.name != 'Operation Phoenix Case Key' && item.name != 'CS:GO Case Key' && item.name != 'Winter Offensive Case Key' && item.name != 'Revolver Case Key' && item.name != 'Operation Vanguard Case Key' && item.name != 'Operation Wildfire Case Key' && item.name != 'Shadow Case Key' && item.name != 'Operation Breakout Case Key' && item.name != 'Chroma Case Key' && item.name != 'Huntsman Case Key' && item.name != 'Falchion Case Key' && item.name != 'Chroma 2 Case Key') {
                        $("#inventory").html($("#inventory").html() + "<li class='col 2' style='padding:8px;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px'><div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light' style='margin:0%;min-height:295px;width:245.438px;border-radius: 15px;' id='" + item.id + "'><div class='iteam' style='text-decoration: underline;text-align: left'>" + item.name + "</div><div class='condition' style='text-align: left;text-size:13px'>" + item.condition + "</div><div class='center-align' style='padding:6%'><img title=\"" + item.originalname + "\" draggable='false' src='https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/" + item.iconurl + "/200fx200'><div class 'floatvalue'>Float: 0.11503319442272186<div class='bitskinscomp' style='font-weight: normal;font-size:12px'>" + message + "</div><div class='buyer-price center-align'>$" + numberWithCommas(item.price) + "</li></div></div>");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Which adds each `item` in array to the `html` and then shows there. `items` array containts JSON, which could be `1000` different items. How could I add `infinite scroll` on that JavaScript? Example: It will show first 50 items, then if you scroll another 50.. Also, sort them by the price (I got it in code already). Is there anyone who could give me help how could I do something like that? I can also provide more code if needed! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not ask the same question repeatedl (either by *you* reposting the question, or by your colleagues re-asking the question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087156/). This is regarded as noise on Stack Overflow. If your question is closed as unanswerable or did not attract responses, then the first thing to do is to *improve the question*; some guidance for this is [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Low-quality or unanswerable questions will typically be closed, but can be re-opened if improved or clarified (as appropriate).